# Unable to migrate core data model with attribute type change

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, migration

I have a core data model with an entity containing a load of attributes. One of these attributes is:

```
dateTime: String
```

I now want to change the type to Date. I understand that this cannot be done with lightweight migration. However, I am a little lost with how to migrate this, even if it is a small change.

I created a second model version and amended the dateTime attribute type to Date.

I then created a mapping model and changed the Value Expression to:

```
FUNCTION($entityPolicy, "dateTimeStringToDateDate:" , $source.dateTime)
```

Finally I created a new class as follows:

```
class DateTimeTransformationPolicy: NSEntityMigrationPolicy {

}
```

And I set the custom policy as

```
<*MyApp*>.DateTimeTransformationPolicy
```

This is where I have come unstuck. Most of the examples I have found involve changing relationships etc. whereas here I just want to change the type of one attribute. Any direction on this would be greatly appreciated.

Initially (although I know it's wrong) I did add the following method into the DateTimeTransformationPolicy class:

```
func dateTimeStringToDate(date: String) -> Date {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    let date = formatter.date(from: date)
    return date ?? Date()
}
```

Again, I know I'm barking up the wrong tree here, but in any case the method is not even being called when I try and save data.

Comment: Migration doesn’t happen when you save changes. It happens when you first load the persistent store, usually when your app launches. Core Data notices that migration is necessary and migrates everything at once. That method should only be canned during migration, not when saving changes.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the answer, that’s good to know. However I haven’t hit that method once as I placed a break point on it straight away. Also not sure about my method anyway. Will passing in date: String work? I mean will this pas in the date strings automatically?

Comment: The function will be called with values from before migration. Since the old data type is `String`, that's what will be passed in. For what it's worth, the only time that function should be called is if (a) the current data model is the new one that uses a Date instead of a String, and (b) the current persistent store contains data from the old model that still uses a String. And, it would only be called during the first time you load the data, during migration, and never again.